# Fastest binary diff encoder/decoder for compact framework / phone 7

Tags: .net, encoding, compact-framework, windows-phone-7, diff

I need to synchronize application state between compact framework devices. (And eventually windows phone 7 devices). Since this information doesn't always change that much, and it can be relatively large I was thinking on using binary diffs to optimize transfers. Something like VCDIFF or bsdiff would probably work great. I need both the decoder and the encoder.
Is there an implementation that would work with the compact framework? (if it also works with wp7 even better). Managed C# code is preferred, but I am fine with porting something from the full .NET framework to CF or wrapping Native C or C++ code. Speed is a priority so if anyone knows more than one option, a hint on which is faster is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will be of much help but the only binary serializer I know off for WP7 is Sharp

http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html